# Page Selector with search box not working properly

Tags: sxa, content-search

I'm using sitecore 9.1.1 and SXA 1.8.1.

I have a page on which i added the following components:
1- search result
2- search box with suggestion mode "show search result as prediction"
3- Date Filter
4- page selector

The problem is: when i search with a query in the search box such that the returned search **result count** is **less than** the **pagesize** of the search result, the API request gets called forever ( i get infinite API requests in the Network).

However if the **result count** is **equal to or greater** than the **pagesize**, the API gets called once and everything goes normal.

When i tried to debug "component-seacrh-page-selector" i found that the case where result count < pagesize is causing this problem because it has a timeout function in which it keeps updating the hashobj thus calling the search API again and again forever.

Mentioning that: if the datefilter has any value, the problem of infinite API requests no longer happens.

[image]

Any idea what might be the reason for this strange behaviour?

Comment: This issue has already been fixed in SXA 1.9. If I will find some time tomorrow I will try to find the fix and describe it here. As far as I remember 2/3 JS files was updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I've already mentioned in the comment - that is known the issue. It is already fixed in the SXA 1.9.

You can try to update the script on your side. Please change the `setTimeout()` function to something like that:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    hashObj = queryModel.parseHashParameters(window.location.hash);
    param = data.searchResultsSignature !== "" ? data.searchResultsSignature + "_e" : "e";
    if (hash[param] !== "0") {
        hashObj[param] = 0;
        Backbone.history.navigate(that.createFirstPageUrlHash(hashObj), { trigger: true, replace: true });
    }
}, 100);
```

Also, add `param` parameter to the `var` statement which is on the beginning of `handleLoadedData()` function.

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved the issue at my side. It's now working as expected.